# Solutions to $a(m^2-a^2)=b(m^2-b^2)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, triangles, sums-of-squares

This problem has to do with congrua. First consider the equation:
$$x^2-y^2=y^2-z^2$$
Which is 3 squares that from an arithmetic sequence. The common difference is called a congruum. I'm looking to parametrize pairs of equal congrua, meaning a congruum such that there are 2 arithmetic sequences (or more). For example: $840$
$$47^2-37^2=37^2-23^2=840=41^2-29^2=29^2-1^2$$
Individual congruum can been parametrized as follows:
$$x=m^2+2mn-n^2$$
$$y=m^2+n^2$$
$$z=n^2+2mn-m^2$$
And the conruum itself is: $4mn(m^2-n^2)$

For all congruum, either there exists integer $m,n$ as shown above or the congruum is the product of a square and another congruum (for which $m, n$ exist).

With that out of the way, for a pair of equal congrua, there will exist $m,n,p,q$ such that:
$$mn(m^2-n^2)=pq(p^2-q^2)$$
If this can be parametrized then great! If not, then it would still be great help to parametrize solutions for this simpler equation. (Which the same equation as above except choose $m=p$)
$$n(m^2-n^2)=q(m^2-q^2)$$
One solution is:$m=7,n=3,q=5$

Note:
$$n(m^2-n^2)=q(m^2-q^2)\implies n(m^2-n^2)=q(m^2-q^2)=(n+q)((n+q)^2-m^2)$$

Comment: somewhat related to parametrizing solutions to integer pythagorean triples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation
$$a(m^2 - a^2) = b(m^2 - b^2)\tag1$$
by [factoring](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5Ba(m%5E2%20-%20a%5E2)%20-%20b(m%5E2%20-%20b%5E2)%5D) is equivalent to solving
$$a^2+ab+b^2=m^2$$
Do the transformation $a=e-f,\;b=2f$ and it reduces to,
$$e^2+3f^2=m^2$$
The complete solution to this is
$$(e,\;f,\;m) = (u^2-3v^2,\;2uv,\; u^2+3v^2)$$
For your more general equation
$$pq(p^2-q^2)=rs(r^2-s^2)\tag2$$
This is equivalent to
$$(p+qi)^4+(r-si)^4=(p-qi)^4+(r+si)^4$$
with the *imaginary unit* $i=\sqrt{-1}$. This was considered by Euler et al and can be solved by an *elliptic cur*ve, hence there are infinitely many parameterizations. One small example by L. Lander is,
$$(p,\;q,\;r,\;s) = (v^5-2v,\;v^5+v,\;-2v^4+1,\;v^4+1)$$
From this initial rational point, one can find an infinite more.

Comment: In the first problem we may have both $a,b$ odd sometimes:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_a_120.C2.B0_angle

Comment: http://www.had2know.com/academics/integer-triangles-120-degree-angle.html

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for the reference. I didn't realize $a^2+ab+b^2=c^2$ had a nice geometric interpretation.

Comment: I've been reading the page you got that parametrization from. Do you understand how one would find more of the other "infinitely many parametrizations"?